# How to a list<string> to Neo4j Through Neo4jClient?

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I am trying to send a list of strings to Neo4j using Neo4jClient to be used in a FOREACH cypher loop. The problem I am facing is that instead to creating different nodes for each string , the program creates just one node with the property Name set as the complete comma separated list.

The Code I am Using :

```
GraphClient graphClient = new GraphClient(new Uri("http://neo4j:a@localhost:7474/db/data"));
        graphClient.Connect();
        graphClient.Cypher
          .With("[{listTags}] AS T1")
          .ForEach("( n in T1| Merge (p: NPT {Name: n})")
          .OnCreate().Set("p.Mod =0")
          .OnMatch().Set("p.Mod = 0)")
           .WithParams(new { listTags = ResultString })
          .ExecuteWithoutResults();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. Instead of using `.With("[{listTags}] AS T1")` I changed it to `.With("{listTags} AS T1")`. ( Dropped the Square Brackets). It Works Now. Thanks anyways.